# Upgrade library for different PHP version

Tags: php, composer-php

I've a legacy project that runs on PHP/5.3.3 (production). I need to upgrade [phpmyadmin/motranslator](https://packagist.org/packages/phpmyadmin/motranslator) from 3.3 to 4.0 to apply a bugfix. I runComposer locally and then upload via FTP.

If I run PHP/5.3 locally then download fails due to a SSL error:

> ```
> Downloading (failed)    Update failed (The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/expression-language/zipball/422bf02386ab46f615d1d784b771599357461d73"
> file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1.
> OpenSSL Error messages:
>     error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
>     Failed to enable crypto
>     failed to open stream: operation failed)
> ```

If I run a later version:

> This package requires php ~5.3.0 but your PHP version (7.2.3) does not satisfy that requirement

The `--ignore-platform-reqs` switch installs dependencies that require PHP/7 and won't run in production.

If feel that the `platform` option is the way to go but I can't grasp it:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.3.0",
        "phpmyadmin/motranslator": "^4.0",
        "ptlis/conneg": "^4.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.3.3"
        }
    }
}
```

… triggers a hundred lines like these:

> symfony/expression-language v4.0.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.2.3) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.3) does not satisfy that requirement

How should I proceed?

Comment: "I've a legacy project that runs on PHP/5.3.3" — Upgrade it immediately!  [PHP 5.3 hit end of life over three and a half years ago](http://php.net/eol.php)! Running it is a serious security risk. Invest your time in removing the dependencies on legacy features instead of making it work on dead versions of PHP.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, "I've" was just a figure of speach, I actually meant "My boss' client has". Whatever, thank you for the tip. Rewriting a monster app written by a coworker who left the company 6 years ago may take a few days—in the meantime I'd appreciate a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to an older version of OpenSSL bundled with your PHP installation.

Since you have `platform` config for PHP set at 5.3.3, everything should work if you just remove `"php": "~5.3.0"` from your `composer.json` file. This will allow `composer install` to proceed and install packages compatible with PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Thank you! In projects with a fixed live environment is it better to just omit `php` from `"require"` as a general rule and only set it in `platform`?

Comment: I wouldn't remove it unless it is absolutely necessary, like here. While `platform` only makes sure to install packages compatible with PHP version you choose, with `php` version constraint, Composer will not actually run on conflicting PHP versions, which might be a good thing to enforce.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that [motranslator requirements](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/motranslator/blob/303e3d636704c59f971d05325cd9d18f03b41d81/composer.json#L18) don't consider dependencies properly:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "symfony/expression-language": "^4.0 || ^3.2 || ^2.8"
},
```

… but [oldest supported expression-language requirements](https://github.com/symfony/expression-language/blob/v2.8.0/composer.json#L18) say:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9"
},
```

This probably explains some of my troubles. I'm sharing this as alternative answer because it kind of deviates from the original question.